# How to do the nearest neighborhood algrorithm on processing

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, processing

I need to code the nearest neighborhood algorithm in processing but I'm having trouble implementing the algorithm into pseudo code. I have a template with my array and all the numbers in the table I'm using now I just need to use the algorithm. I'm using 2D arrays. Please can someone help

Comment: What kind of data is stored in the 2D array? Is it an array of points where each point is represented as an array?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the 2D array `A` you're mentioning is the array of `n` points where each point---from, say, `d`-dimensional Euclidean space `R^d`---is represented as an array of size `d`.

I'll assume that the nearest *neighborhood* problem is to return the set of points within distance `R` of the given point `p`, i.e., `{q in A | d(p,q) < =R}`.

```
vector<int> neighborhood(double** points, int n, int d, int* p, double R) {
    vector<int> result; // the set of indices of points from the neighborhood
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (distance(a, i, d, p) <= R) {
            result.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The algorithm runs in time `O(nd)`. The function `distance` computes the distance between two points represented as arrays of size `d` of doubles.